# How to fetch an image and return it's url in react Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, next.js

fetching my api from my database I'm trying to get produc.image and
return it's url do you know guys how to do it?

ex: {product.image} to => url string

```
const Products: React.FC = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Props[]>([]);
  const { addItem, removeItem } = useShoppingCart();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/products/`);
        setProducts(res.data);
    }
    catch (err) {
     
    }
  }

    fetchProduct();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="products">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.sku} className="product">
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} /> <-- Pass image to it's url string
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried running your code to see what's the error? PS: You will also need to null check the products array in your JSX code

Comment: Can you output the `res.data` you get back?

Comment: Is fetching you have the problem with or the return?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to render your fetch before it is resolved

Comment: In the server my app is a file but in next its not returning anything, I would like to get the image from the api and return the image url.

Comment: apparently I'm consuming the api, but it works when Its an URL only, from my Image I in the api I wanna retrieve it's URL